# How can we pass runtime parameter in jenkins job like password

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

While the jenkins job is running it is asking for credential like:
**[sshexec] Enter password for datasource user**

Please let me know how we can proceed further on this.

Comment: Use [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) step.

Comment: Also the `password` parameter type for non-interactive input.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin on Jenkins designed for that: Credential plugin
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin

You set-up your data within this plugin, and then you can re-use later in your build. The same way as if they were regular shell variable.

```
spawn ssh id@server
match_max 100000
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$your_password\r"
send -- "\r"
interact
```

But if I may provide a recommendation, this is not the best way to connect in SSH.

You should use ssh key will make you get ride of the password step.

You generate your key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

You push it to your server:

```
ssh-copy-id id@server
```

And then you can log-in without any password needed:

```
ssh id@server
```